# Use friend's adMob in my android application

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Years ago google has cancelled my google ad sense (and adMob) account. I have an active playstore account to publish my own android applications.

The question is if I can add my friend's adMob account in my application and publishing it in my playstore publish account.

Will google ban me for this?!

Comment: why don't you create a new one adMob doesn't have any prerequisite for publishing ads to your app.

Comment: But that adMob account is linked with my adSense account. Isn't it? i think that is not possible to have 2 adSense accounts. That is right?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple Play Store accounts and associate them with one admob account. However, if one of you gets banned from Play Store, both of you will be banned eventually.

Comment: Also, in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-multiple-users-AdMob-IDs-in-one-Google-Play-developers-account) it says you can only have one Admob account. It may not be certain but if one you gets banned other account will also be banned because of association.

Comment: The problem is my google AdSense and AdMob are banned. I can not do a new one]

Comment: what you can do is ask your (mother sister for example) and use their identity to create a new adsense account NOTE never use same address and never use it on the same domain!

Comment: My Play Store account is banned and after that i searched every web page. Getting banned from Play Store is very serious compared to Admob. I got all 3 strikes at once and appeal does nothing whether you were awere or not but when you are banned other accounts associated with you also get banned eventually. I read even if a developer banned working on a company uses email address and makes some association with company, company gets banned too. The guy worked hard to prove that there were no association between the guy and them. There are lots of stories like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have answered under question, it's not certain if you can or not but if one of you gets banned from Play Store, other associated account will get banned eventually. It's not that uncommon to get banned even without knowing why. It does not worth taking that risk. There are other ad networks like FAN, StartApp, Heyzap and more, your Play Store account worths a lot more than that since it's for good.

I got banned and my whole income was from Play Store and all gone now. They also stop publishing ads in my apps because my apps removed from Play Store(they are valid apps with no issue regarding to publisher policies) even if those apps are published and still available on other markets.

Answer (score 1):

No. Google adMob documentation didn't say anything like this. I think you can use it.